# Android: intent started, but which parameters to pass?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to add support for several navigation applications in my app. I know how to start another activity as intent and pass parameters - but is there any way to check the naming of the parameters I should pass? For example: Navigon should start with routing calculation and instructions immediately after starting from within my application. So far, I'm not even sure Navigon supports parameter passing, but I don't even know how to figure that out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the documentation for each app you're interested in supporting. They *should* have it laid out somewhere. If they don't, they might not support explicit intent extras.

For example, Navigon has their options laid out here(found by searching "android navigon intent"):

http://www.navigon.com/portal/common/faq/files/online_documents/NAVIGON_Android_public_Intent.pdf

Comment: You sir, are my hero. I searched for "android navigon parameters" where the linked PDF document is the 3rd or 4th result, but I guess I just overlooked it :)
But I suppose there is no way to "hack" an activity to print the parameters it is checking, right?

Comment: Nah, that would be too easy ;)